# Upper bound of an operation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let $L$ be the following operation
$$L: = I - \Delta, $$
from $C(R^2)$ to $C(R)$, where $I$ is the identity operation and $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operation. From the equation $Lu = f$, where $f$ is a known function, we have
$$u = {L^{ - 1}}f.$$
By taking the norm, from both sides of the last equation, we have
$${\left\| u \right\|_p} = {\left\| {{L^{ - 1}}f} \right\|_p} \leqslant {\left\| {{L^{ - 1}}} \right\|_p}{\left\| f \right\|_p}$$
Now, I need an upper bound for ${\left\| {{L^{ - 1}}} \right\|_p}$.
I will appreciate it if someone helps me to find that upper bound.

Comment: How does the Laplacian operate on $\mathbb{R}^2$? I guess you mean some space of functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a heat kernel approach: Consider the heat semigroup $(e^{t\Delta})$. It is well known (and can be seen quite easily using the Fourier transform) that
$$
e^{t\Delta}f(x)=(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4t}}f(y)\,dy.
$$
Direct computation shows that $\|e^{t\Delta}f\|_p\leq \|f\|_p$. In fact, it suffices to show this for $p=2$ and $p=\infty$; the other cases follow by interpolation and duality.

The resolvent is the Laplace transform of the heat semigroup, that is,
$$
(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}f=\int_0^\infty e^{-t\lambda}e^{t\Delta}f\,dt.
$$
Thus
$$
\|(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}f\|_p\leq \int_0^\infty e^{-t\lambda}\|e^{t\Delta}f\|_p\,dt\leq \|f\|_p\int_0^\infty e^{-t\lambda}\,dt=\frac 1{\lambda}\|f\|_p.
$$
In your particular case you get $\|L^{-1}\|_{p\to p}\leq 1$.

Comment: Thank you @MaoWao, in the last line, do you mean $\left\| {{L^{ - 1}}} \right\| \leqslant 1$?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you very much @MaoWao. I would be very grateful if you introduce me to a book that contains the above contents and definitions.

Comment: I can recommend Davies' book on heat kernels (don't remember the exact title).